# What does "paint-by-numbers" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "paint-by-numbers" in

```
"Because this drama is paint-by-numbers ..."
```

mean?

Context: https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2016/oct/19/chance-review-hugh-laurie-hulu ( 2nd paragraph )

Comment: [*Paint-by-numbers*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/paint-by-numbers): something done mechanically and without real skill.

Comment: "Paint by numbers" was a big thing back around 1960. (Ie, before computer games.) You'd go into Woolworth's and buy a paint-by-number kit, take it home, create the enclosed work of art (as pictured on the cover of the box), and hang it on the wall in your living room. Sometimes the results would be quite good, other times, uh, less than remarkable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A paint-by-numbers kit consists of a prepared board printed with lines enclosing areas together with small pots of paint and a brush. Each pot of paint has a number assigned to it and each area on the board has one of the numbers printed in it.

The kit is used by filling each area with the paint associated with the number printed in the area. When all the areas are painted a picture is produced.

The picture is not, strictly, a work of art since the original picture was produced by a professional artist and the person using the kit is merely producing a copy with no individual expression.

Andy Warhol produced several pictures inspired by paint-by-numbers kits called Do it Yourself of which [this](https://www.artsy.net/artwork/andy-warhol-do-it-yourself-violin) is an example.

The quote in the question compares the play to a painting produced by the paint-by-numbers process (not, of course, the Warhol pieces). This comparison implies that the play is derivative, formulaic and lacking in originality; in short not very good at all.

Comment: It needs to be understood that these were different from the "color-by-number" coloring books for the kiddies, for which the kids used their own crayons or colored pencils.  "Paint-by-number" kits were generally intended for adults or older children. Some of these, in the right hands, produced fairly impressive results.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes I did a couple of them as an older child. The thing is that there is no merging of areas of colour and, more importantly, no interpretation on the part of the person using the kit: it's more of a reproduction system than original artwork. That's why Warhol was so taken with it, he was fascinated by reproduction techniques and even called his studio The Factory.